# Using both @JsonSerializer and @JsonView

Tags: json, jackson, jax-rs

I'm using jax-rs to define an `@JsonView` on the `@GET` method for a REST API. In one of the objects being returned, I have a custom serializer defined using `@JsonSerializer`. It also has `@JsonView` on it. What I realized is even though the object isn't included in the JsonView defined on the GET, it is still serializing the object but not including it in the JSON response. The issue is, due to the type of object being serialized, extra (and slow) code will be unnecessarily invoked during serialization. When I try to `getActiveView()` on the `SerializerProvider` passed into my custom serializer, I'm getting null. Without knowing that, I'm not sure how I can skip the serialization process. Stepping through the entire stack of Jackson calls when the custom serializer gets called, I see nothing indicating it is aware of the view set on the endpoint.

Assuming I'm not completely off on my approach, how can I know what, if any, view is set on the endpoint in the custom serializer?

To help visualize the problem -

Example Endpoint

```
    @GET
    @JsonView(Views.AView.class)
    public Response getSomething(...) {
        ...
    }
```

POJO with annotations -

```
...
@JsonSerialize(using = ASerializer.class)
@JsonView(Views.AView.class)
private Set<Stuff> stuffList;
...
```

Lastly  -

```
public class ASerializer<T> extends JsonSerializer<T> {


@Override
public void serialize(T value, JsonGenerator gen,
        SerializerProvider serializers) throws IOException,
        JsonProcessingException {

            //It would be nice to check in here what the active view is....


}
```

Comment: could you show the class(es) you are talking about?

Comment: I added some code as an example. I've bypassed the problem at this point using different logic where I didn't need to care about the view anymore, but I still feel like what I originally wanted to do should be possible.

Comment: It've been a long time but did you find the solution to your problem?

Comment: Yes I found something.

Answer (score 1):

The serializer can obtain the view.

```
  private static class MaskedSerializer extends 
  JsonSerializer {
    public void serialize(String value, JsonGenerator gen, SerializerProvider serializers) throws IOException, JsonProcessingException {
      Class view = serializers.getActiveView();
      gen.writeString(Views.External.class.equals(view)
        ? mask(value) : value); 
    }
  }
```